# Move changes from master to develop branch (using GIT)

Tags: git

The way I use GIT when developing a new feature or fixing a bug is to create a new branch from the master branch to work on then, once I have finished developing on that branch, merge it back into the master branch.

Now, lets say I have the **master**, **bug_fix_1**, **feature_1** and **feature_2** branches. The development of feature_1 has been put on the back-burner because feature_2 became a priority. The bug_fix_1 has now been fixed and merged back into master. The feature_2 branch has also now been completed and merged back into master. As a result I have deleted both these branches and am now left with master and feature_1.

How do I get the changes **from bug_fix_1** and **feature_2** (now in the master branch) into the **feature_1** branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already merged **bug_fix_1** and **feature_2** branches with **master**,

then your **master** has all the changes from **bug_fix_1 and feature_2**

> git checkout feature_1
>
> git merge master

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

> ```
> git checkout feature_1
> git merge bug_fix_1
> git merge feature_2
> ```

Or am I missing something?